# Opencart affiliate commission

Tags: opencart, affiliate, opencart-module

I want to set affiliate commission but there are **two condition**, **first** is Affiliate member payout will take 10% for all sign up. If an affiliate partner purchase as a returning customer, the payout will be taking as 10% and **second** is Returning customer cash payout will take 8%. 
How it possible this. There are any plugin for that which provide me that type functionality.

Comment: I can develop one for you.

Comment: Thanks, But I did

Comment: Can you share with me?